# Semantic UI React Checkbox centering

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, center, semantic-ui

Is there a way to center the checkbox in react? I'm using Semantic UI react Checkbox module.
The language used is Typescript. I did an example of the before and after to show what I mean. I tried adding different attributes and tried looking on google, but I wasn't able to find anything.
Before:

[image: See the before picture here]

After:

[image: See the after picture here]

Here is an example of the code:
[Image of an example of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBnJp.png)

Comment: Please share the regarding code. Without it, we can't help you.

Comment: The main thing is that inside the <Form.Checkbox> I have a label attribute containing my text. I'm trying to find a way to make the checkbox go in the middle left side of that text. See the pictures I posted as reference.

Comment: Without code we cannot help you. There are dozens of solutions for this, but it depends on your code.

Comment: I updated the question to include an example of what my code looks like. Basically the label attribute contains my text and I want to make the checkbox be centered on the left side.